# About Rollback and commit in Gridview Deleting Event

Tags: vb.net, gridview

When writing gridview Event, We must write the Commit  and Rollback in  event. Can not run the Event  if don't write  Commit. I want to know what for writing  commit and rollback???what a differences  between commit and rollback????

Comment: please rephrase your question. take sometime to ask it so that others will understand the question. otherwise this will be closed pretty soon :)

Answer (score 0):

COMMIT :
To make the changes done in a transaction permanent issue the COMMIT statement.
The syntax of COMMIT Statement is
COMMIT  [WORK]  [COMMENT ‘your comment’];
WORK is optional.
COMMENT is also optional, specify this if you want to identify this transaction in data dictionary DBA_2PC_PENDING.

Example :
insert into emp (empno,ename,sal) values (101,’Abid’,2300);
commit;

ROLLBACK :
To rollback the changes done in a transaction give rollback statement. Rollback restore the state of the database to the last commit point.

Example :
delete from emp;
rollback;          /* undo the changes */